# javascript error after toggle modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am just new to bootstrap and I am getting a javascript error that I don't know how to manage.

I have a datatable with checkboxes in the first column. After selecting some checkboxes, you can click on two buttons that open a modal with different messages for accepting or cancelling. But if there is no checkbox checked I show an info alert (also bootstrap) and I need to "close" the modal.

This is the **js code**:

```
$('#actionsModal').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {

    var action = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
    var total = $('input[id^="checkboxRol"]:checked').length;

    var message = "", object = "", confirmation = "";
    if(total == 0){
        $('.alert-info').show();


        // -----------------------------------------------------
        // this is the line giving the error!!!
        $('#actionsModal').modal("toggle");
        // -----------------------------------------------------


    }
    else if(total > 1){
        message = "Va a " + action + " los " + total + " objetos seleccionados:";
        confirmation = "¿Desea realizar esta operación?";
    }
    else{
        message = "Va a " + action + " el objeto:";
        object = "-obtener nombre-<br><br>";
        confirmation = "¿Desea realizar esta operación?";
    }

    $(e.currentTarget).find('span[id="message"]').html(message);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('span[id="object"]').html(object);
    $(e.currentTarget).find('span[id="confirmation"]').html(confirmation);
});
```

The **js error** is: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Any idea? Maybe I could use another type of bootstrap entities, and using just modals for simple buttons or links clicks.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Replace that line for this e.preventDefault()

Comment: i think u ve multiple modal instance at the same time... bootstrap does not support it

Comment: @JesúsQuintana this was really useful but now I have lost the vertical scroll bar, so the screen gets fixed. Maybe applying preventDefault() to another object?

Comment: The vertical scroll of what? Maybe another error in the console?

Comment: The vertical scroll of the main page. No, there isn't any JS error.

Now the situation after the e.preventDefault() is that the modal is not shown, the info alert is visible, but the vertical scroll has dissapeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!

In the end it was only necessary to replace the 'show.bs.modal' event by **'shown.bs.modal'** event

Now the line:

```
$('#actionsModal').modal("toggle");
```

does not create an infinite call.

Thanks @JesúsQuintana

Answer (score 1):

If you want to just close modal use

```
$('#actionsModal').modal("hide");
```

instead of toggle. I am not sure if it help for your case but it can prevent unwanted infinite recursion on show.bs.modal event (which is you problem)